# wrote code for binding in jndi and its throwing null pointer exception I am not sure whats wrong with the configuration

Tags: java, eclipse, jndi

trying to learn jndi started with binding but its showing null pointer exception i think there is something wrong with  the configuration

error is

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at com.sun.jndi.fscontext.RefFSContext.addObjectToBindings(RefFSContext.java:484)
>       at com.sun.jndi.fscontext.RefFSContext.bindObject(RefFSContext.java:337)
>       at com.sun.jndi.fscontext.RefFSContext.bind(RefFSContext.java:169)
>       at com.sun.jndi.fscontext.FSContext.bind(FSContext.java:167)
>       at javax.naming.InitialContext.bind(InitialContext.java:425)
>       at ContextExample.main(ContextExample.java:15)

configured build path and copy and paste of fscontext.jar file

it should make file in location /home:/naveen:/jndi with  all information that a monkeySteven hold,(just trying to implement a code form youtube)

```
public static void main(String []args) throws NamingException
{
    Hashtable<String,String> environment = new Hashtable<String,String>();
    environment.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,"com.sun.jndi.fscontext.RefFSContextFactory");
    environment.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL,"file:/home:/naveen:/jndi");
    Context context = new InitialContext(environment);
    Monkey monkeySteven = new Monkey("steven","bananas",true);
    context.bind("monkey steven",monkeySteven);

}
```

Comment: do you see the location bound in JNDI tree?

Comment: I do not have any idea about it,I am new to this technology how can I check it.

Comment: start your server and go to http://localhost:8080/jmx-console in the browser

Answer (score 0):

file:/home:/naveen:/jndi : delete this file from the directory or use rebind instead of bind